# how can I set the first layer to have a learning rate of 0.00001 and the last layer to have a learning rate of 0.001?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In the following program, how can I set the first layer to have a learning rate of 0.00001 and the last layer to have a learning rate of 0.001?

```
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool2d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def convolutional_neural_network(x):

    weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 20])),
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 20, 40])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7 * 7 * 40, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}
    biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20])),
              'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([40])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1'])) + biases['b_conv1']
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']))+ biases['b_conv2']
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)
    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 40])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)
    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about this. The easiest is probably to create a separate [optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Optimizers) for each different learning rate (though you'll need to restructure things to pass the variables to your optimizers, and return a training op):

```
def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 20])),
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 20, 40])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7 * 7 * 40, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}
    biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20])),
              'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([40])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1'])) + biases['b_conv1']
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']))+ biases['b_conv2']
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)
    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 40])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)
    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logit‌​s=prediction, labels=y))

    # Assuming that the convolutional layers are considered the "first layer".
    opt1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001)
    train1_op = opt1.minimize(cost, var_list=[
        weights['W_conv1'], weights['W_conv2'], biases['b_conv1'], biases['b_conv2']])

    # Assuming that the fully connected and softmax layers are considered the
    # "last layer".
    opt2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
    train2_op = opt2.minimize(cost, var_list=[
        weights['W_fc'], weights['out'], biases['b_fc'], biases['out']])

    train_op = tf.group(train1_op, train2_op)
    return output, train_op

prediction, optimizer = convolutional_neural_network(x)
```

An alternative approach would be to use [`tf.train.Optimizer.compute_gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients) to compute gradients for all of the variables, then multiply each gradient by the appropriate factor before passing it to [`tf.train.Optimizer.apply_gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#apply_gradients).

Comment: train1_op = opt1.minimize(var_list=[...])  # first layer variables
    how do that in In detail and how apply in my code

Comment: You might need to restructure your program a bit, since the variables are local to `convolutional_neural_network()`. For example, if you returned the `weights` and `biases` dictionary you might do `train1_op = opt1.minimize(var_list=[weights['W_conv1'], biases['b_conv1']])` to select the weights/biases from the first convolutional layer.

Comment: can you  restructure my program if you please

Comment: in code 
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)   how edit

Comment: train1_op = opt1.minimize(var_list=[
        weights['W_conv1'], biases['b_conv1'], biases['b_conv2']])
TypeError: minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'loss'

Comment: I added the missing `cost` to the program... have a look.

Comment: Thanks to your efforts